# Why doesn't MongoDB cursor.maxTimeMS work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Maybe I'm missing something, but according to the documentation and all the posts online, setting

```
cursor.maxTimeMS(1000).toArray(...)
```

should time out after 1000ms, and MongoDB should kill the operation after timeout.

But none of this is happening.

First, there is no timeout. It keeps going.

Second, I check `db.currentOp()` and the operation is still there, eating up all the memory. This later adds up and crashes the database with OOM.

Anyway running `db.currentOp()` after several minutes of no response prints:

```
{
  "inprog" : [
    {
        "host" : "db2:27017",
        "desc" : "conn20",
        "connectionId" : 20,
        "client" : "127.0.0.1:59214",
        "clientMetadata" : {
            "driver" : {
                "name" : "nodejs",
                "version" : "3.1.4"
            },
            "os" : {
                "type" : "Linux",
                "name" : "linux",
                "architecture" : "x64",
                "version" : "4.15.0-30-generic"
            },
            "platform" : "Node.js v8.10.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.3"
        },
        "active" : true,
        "currentOpTime" : "2018-09-14T00:10:29.903+0000",
        "opid" : 11056,
        "lsid" : {
            "id" : UUID("78a2d853-30bf-4d6d-a208-0a150d9bf8be"),
            "uid" : BinData(0,"47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=")
        },
        "secs_running" : NumberLong(649),
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(649968360),
        "op" : "command",
```

As you can see, this has been running for 649 seconds, even though I explicitly specified 1000ms.

What is going on here? I've been pulling my hair out for two days and can't figure this out.

Comment: What's the version of your MongoDB server?

Comment: it's ver 4.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and had to update the `mongodb` driver from `3.1.1` to `3.3.5` and it worked like a charm!